# Remove radiobuttons within form

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, invisible

I'm trying to remove my radio buttons within a form because it has to look like buttons but in a form (for filtering). I've tried `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` but both did not work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
form [type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    padding: red 2px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="categorieen" checked>Categorieen
  <p>99 verhalen</p>
</form>
```

Comment: The minimal code you have shown basically works, see https://jsfiddle.net/u9ofycjz/ Please give a proper [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: If I click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52873835/edit) and then `[<>]` and paste your code, it works as expected. You could have made a [mcve] too

Comment: `padding: red 2px;` is not valid css. If you want to show radio buttons as buttons, use combination of label with hidden radio button to add custom css. Check the following example to get started -> https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq

Comment: @fen1x - too many changes to the original code can hide the issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this please form end tag is not closing properly

```
  form input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
        padding: red 2px;
    }
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="categorieen" checked>Categorieen
  <p>99 verhalen</p>
</form>
```

Comment: How is this different from the original code in question?

Comment: end tag is not closing correctly now fix by fen1x during editing  :)